# solr filter query with opposite conditions on same field

Tags: solr

I was trying to get solr records with filter conditions on the single(same) field, the condition is **either middleName should be null or middleName should be 'BOH'.** I am using below expression which is not working. Any other options for that?

```
"fq":"-middleName:[* TO *] OR middleName:BOH"
```

At the sametime, if I change the condition as **middleName should have value or middleName should be 'BOH',** it is working, any clue?

```
"fq":"middleName:[* TO *] OR middleName:BOH"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two things:

1. it is fq=... not fq:... notice the equals
2. try with

   fq=( * : * AND -middleName:[* TO *]) OR middleName:BOH

Comment: The "fq"-syntax is [from a JSON-structured request](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/JSON+Request+API). And the reason why `*:* -middleName ..` should work is because you need to have something to subtract the hits from. Solr usually appends this in front of your query magically for simple queries, so most people doesn't notice.